# Is it possible for wifi to be connected but not be the active network?

Tags: android

I'm using the android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED to monitor whether wifi is connected, but I'm wondering is it possible for wifi to be connected and ConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() to return a NetworkInfo for a network that's not wifi?

What determines the default active network?